# Multiple spark session in one job submit on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

can we use multiple starts and stop spark sessions in Kubernetes in one submit a job?

like: if I submit one job using this

```
bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://<k8s-apiserver-host>:<k8s-apiserver-port> \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name spark-pi \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<spark-image> \
    local:///path/to/examples.jar
```

In my python code, can I starts and stop spark sessions?

examples:

```
# start spark session
session = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName(appname) \
        .getOrCreate()

## Doing some operations using spark 
session.stop()

## some python code.

# start spark session
session = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName(appname) \
        .getOrCreate()

## Doing some operations using spark 
session.stop()
```

is it possible or not?